# Using Linq to partition a dataset

Tags: c#, linq, compiler-errors, type-inference

Jumping to my conclusion: what do I do to make the compiler let me use GroupJoin?

I have member Double[] rawData, and I find minValue and maxValue.  I want to partition this data so that I can make a bar graph.  My final result will be a OrderedDictionary in which the Key is the center value of each bar of the barchart and the int is the number of items that fall in the range of the bar.

I could write this myself using foreaches and such, but I want to use this experience to learn a little more about Linq.  I am pretty sure I should be using GroupJoin.  (Please correct me if wrong.)

Using minVal, maxVal, and numberOfBars, I have composed a List bar, in which xRange represent a single bar in the barchart.

I am getting a certain compiler error, and I just can't figure out how to get past it:

The type arguments for method 'System.Linq.Enumerable.GroupJoin(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, System.Func, System.Func, System.Func,TResult>)' cannot be inferred from the usage. Try specifying the type arguments explicitly.

So based on that, here is my method call (does not compile):

```
var result = bars.GroupJoin(
            inner: this.rawData,
            outerKeySelector: bar => bar,
            innerKeySelector: samplePoint => samplePoint,
            resultSelector: (bar, samplePoints) => samplePoints
            );
```

(Later I will compose this into the dictionary, just taking samplePoints.Count.)

I also have tried the overload where I pass a lambda for comparer:

Finally, by way of background, hereis the xRange class:

```
internal class xRange : IEqualityComparer
{
    public xRange(Double low, Double high)
    {
        lowSide = low;
        highSide = high;
    }

    public Double lowSide { get; set; }
    public Double highSide { get; set; }

    public bool FallsWithin(Double val)
    { return ((val >= this.lowSide) && (val <= this.highSide));  }

    public int Compare(object x, object y)
    {
        xRange range = (xRange)x;
        Double val = (Double)y;
        if (val < range.lowSide) return -1;
        if (val > range.highSide) return 1;
        return 0;
    }

}
```

Advice on any of these points is welcomed (using GroupJoin, correct way to implement IComparer, etc), but my main question is, what do I do to make the compiler let me use GroupJoin?

Comment: You have to join on the same type of value - so if `rawData` is an array of `double` then you need to join on a `double` from `xRange` too. Currently you are trying to join on an `xRange` being equal to a `double` so of course the compiler can't work it out.

Comment: Are you trying to determine the count of each value in `rawData` that `FallsWithin` the `xRange` object?

Comment: Enigmativity: Okay.  If that is true, then why does it even /have/ a comparer overload of the method?

Comment: Enigmativity: Yes, to your second question.

Comment: There's no overload that takes `IEqualityComparer`. There is one that takes `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`, but that still works on joining two keys with the same `TKey` type.

Comment: Okay.  I agree that's it.  GroupJoin is just not intended for this kind of problem I guess.  Thanks.  If you want to make that an Answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joins can only work when you are joining on keys of the same type.

This is the signature that you're trying to use:

```
IEnumerable<TResult> GroupJoin<TOuter, TInner, TKey, TResult>(
    this IEnumerable<TOuter> outer,
    IEnumerable<TInner> inner,
    Func<TOuter, TKey> outerKeySelector,
    Func<TInner, TKey> innerKeySelector,
    Func<TOuter, IEnumerable<TInner>, TResult> resultSelector,
    IEqualityComparer<TKey> comparer
)
```

Note that you are required to provide an instance of `IEqualityComparer<TKey>`, not `IEqualityComparer`, and that both keys must be of type `TKey`.

To get what you want try this query instead:

```
var query =
    from b in bars
    select new
    {
        bar = b,
        count =
            rawData
                .Where(rd => b.FallsWithin(rd))
                .Count(),
    };
```

Comment: This works beautifully.  (It relates to getting a bell curve on noisy data coming from a motionless accelerometer, so it is really cool, to me anyway.)

Answer (score 0):

`GroupJoin` only supports *equi* joins - the inner and outer key *types* must be the same. In your example, the `outerKeySelector` is an xRange and the `innerKeySelector` is a double.

From your requirements, I think something like this might do:

```
var groups = from bar in bars
             from datum in rawData
             where bar.FallsWithin(datum)
             group datum by bar into g
             select new
             { 
                 Mid = (bar.lowSide  + bar.highSide) / 2,
                 Count = g.Count()
             };

// Write a similar extension of SortedDictionary / SortedList if needed.
// Note: this will blow up if two bars have the same Mid.
// Note 2: A dictionary with a double as the key isn't the best idea.
var result = groups.ToDictionary(a => a.Mid, a => a.Count);
```

Comment: Thank you, Ani, for your response.  I did not take the time to plug your response into my code because Enigmativity's response does what I need.